# Downvote (vote down) tooltip is grossly misleading

Tags: support, downvotes

The downvote tool tip on answers is grossly misleading and is causing many users to downvote inappropriately. Please change it.

When hovering over the downvote button, the tooltip says "This answer is not useful."

Many users take this to mean if it does not solve their immediate problem, rather than "This answer is not useful."

However, your own reference indicates otherwise:
From https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down
you state:

> When should I vote down? Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an
>   egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is
>   clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.
>
> You have a limited number of votes per day, and answer down-votes cost
>   you a tiny bit of reputation on top of that; use them wisely.

I propose that you change the tooltip to something like this:

> This is an egregiously, off-topic, non-responsive, or dangerous answer.

Comment: I think we should change the privileges page text to match the tooltip, instead.

Comment: As far as downvotes on this meta question go, voting on meta is different; downvotes on this question are likely because readers disagree with your proposed change.

Comment: If you disagree with my proposed change, that's fine.  Just post a comment saying so, or even better, post an Answer with with you think the tool tip should be.  Then we can all vote on which Answer we like best.

Comment: The tooltip that does need to be changed, is the tooltip on the voting buttons on meta. Because votes on meta actually express disagreement (especially in the case of feature requests). But you wouldn't have known this unless you looked in the help center.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta "Voting is different on Meta"

Comment: Your proposal does not cover the 99% case, "clearly incorrect". The vast majority of unhelpful answers are merely clumsy and the poster had the best of intentions in mind.  The existing tip is fine, it is short and covers all cases.  Do keep in mind that you are not going to enjoy SO much when you don't like incorrect answers getting downvoted.  Or for that matter correct answers, it happens.

Comment: *Many users take this to mean if it does not solve their immediate problem, then "This answer is not useful."* I'm trying to think of an answer that doesn't solve the immediate problem but is useful. If it's useful info but doesn't solve the problem, maybe it should be a comment instead.

Comment: I disagree because asdflkjasd;lfiuohjawperufhjqwpeurohjf;asodfsf

Answer (score 12):

I do not know of any trend such as you describe to downvote answers *because they are not immediately useful to the voter*. It's possible such a trend exists, but you've shown no evidence of it. Instead, I at least, and I strongly suspect most other users, simply vote on our perception of the answer's usefulness as far as we can see.

The current tooltip is certainly terser than the help center (which is actually highly desirable), but it's not wrong: it refers to *general* usefulness, and doesn't attempt to narrow it to personal usefulness. So if users are misinterpreting that, it might be useful to tweak, but I think the suggestion is too long. And if it's too long, users will be less likely to read and properly understand it.

Comment: You said "but I think the suggestion is too long. And if it's too long, users will be less likely to read and properly understand it". --- OK, that's a good point.  Please provide an alternative tool tip you think would be good.  Provide an answer that, IMO, will help make voting a better tool, and I'll even vote for your answer.  :-)

Comment: I don't think personal usefulness is a bad criterion. I certainly downvote answers that are not immediately useful to me, and I don't see why this would be an undesirable trend. Obviously it would be unfortunate if Java programmers were going and downvoting all the C++ answers because they aren't interested in C++. But that's a pretty extreme manifestation. No tweak to the wording is going to help, people who are doing that know what they are doing is silly.

Comment: @CodyGray: Well, any similar situation where the voter does not have the problem described in the question, and does not have a sufficiently related current field of focus to glean anything specific from the answer, would seem to qualify. That still seems pretty silly, but that would be the point.

Answer (score 2):

The help center page does not reflect voting policy or culture. It should be changed to match the tooltip. Anybody can vote for whatever reason they want, and often times that is because the post is not helpful to them. This is the desired behavior and there is nothing that can be done about it.

Comment: That whole help page about downvoting is entirely misleading. In fact some mods won't take your flags seriously if you don't down vote, yet that help page states that you shouldn't downvote if you flag.

Comment: @bjb568:  You said "Anybody can vote for whatever reason they want" --- Of course they can, but the question is shouldn't there be some reasonable criteria for DownVoting that is at least suggested that we all follow?  If people downvote just because they got up on the wrong side of the bed that morning, or it's not how they would have answered the question, then what value is downvoting?  If it is just based on the irrational whelms of the person, it is worthless.

Comment: How would a mod know if you had downvoted? I've never personally had a moderator act inappropriately on a flag I've raised because of how I voted on the post.

Comment: @CodyGray The flag summary lets mods know what action(s) have been taken on it (including down votes)

Comment: @CodyGray Pretty sure yeah, it does on the site where I'm a mod and I can't think of a reason that would be different on SO. I'm talking about the moderator list of flags specifically, and probably the contextual per-page popup that mods get as well. I'm with you though, I don't know of a policy or practice to deny flags on posts that haven't been down voted

Comment: Fascinating! I didn't know this information was provided. Thanks for the update, @Clive.

Comment: @TinyGiant A flag will just bring up the question page with an overlay saying who flagged it and why. Nothing more. There's a page in the mod dashboard which shows how many votes received and given in total to a specific user, which is only designed to detect voting fraud, not track what a user votes exactly. This isn't needed. As far as I can see, mods can't see specific up/down votes for specific posts. So even for mods your votes are *mostly* anonymous.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, if a flagged posts has *no* downvotes, it is pretty obvious that you didn't downvote it.

Comment: @TinyGiant That's true. At any rate, I usually don't downvote non-answers from new users, and not many flags have been declined so far :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, well I've been highly critical of moderators in the past, so that may have something to do with them being highly critical of me. However, I generally downvote every answer that I think is not useful, and non-answers are generally not useful.

Answer (score -42):

**OK, if you don't like the proposal I made in my question, then post your own Answer with what you think the DownVote Tool Tip should be.**

Here's my proposal for the DownVote Tool Tip:

> This is an egregiously, off-topic, non-responsive, or dangerous
>   answer.

If you are down voting my question, then you are saying that it is an invalid question, that I don't have the right to ask it.  Do you really want to do that?  What will happen when the shoe is on the other foot, and you ask a question that others don't like?

I don't know what country you are from, but in the USA we defend the right of everyone to voice their opinion, whether we agree with that opinion or not. In this case it means asking a valid question, regardless of whether or not you agree with the proposed answer.

The last thing you want to do is put a damper on people asking questions that they have researched, or on people offering answers that may not be exactly what YOU are looking for.  You want people to feel free to offer up their best answer, even if it is not exactly constrained to your question.  Otherwise you may be eliminating great solutions that you never even considered.

**All of you people casting downvotes on my question, at least have the guts, the integrity, the courtesy, to offer an Answer of your own.**

Comment: I can defend your right to say something and still tell you it's a terrible idea, without contradiction.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what free speech actually means.  [Here's a place for you to start](https://xkcd.com/1357/), if you're interested in learning more about what it *actually* means.

Comment: `What will happen when the shoe is on the other foot, and you ask a question that others don't like?` I'll answer this rhetorical question anyway.  I'd expect them to express their opinions honestly (although ideally constructively), rather than refusing to indicate that the question is a bad question because they're being bullied into not providing accurate feedback by people who are unable to accept constructive criticism about the quality of their questions.

Comment: @Servy:  You said "They're being bullied into not providing accurate feedback by people who are unable to accept constructive criticism about the quality of their questions."  (1) No one is being bullied.  (2) Most of those who downvote do NOT provide any feedback, let alone "accurate" feedback.  (3) I fully welcome "constructive criticism", but most downvoters are "hit and run", offering nothing.

Comment: @Servy:  You said:  "You seem to misunderstand what free speech actually means". --- Nope, you're wrong.  I completely understand what it means.  YOU don't seem to understand that casting a DownVote without leaving a "constructive criticism" (your words) is like throwing rotten tomatoes at someone.  Doesn't really do any good because you have no idea why: whether they are crazy, have a vengence, or actually have a valid criticism to make.

Comment: And that's fine @JMichaelTX, it's ok not to know. If it's keeping you up at night, you can assume it's because of one of the reasons outlined in the tooltip, or that it's a random nutter

Comment: @JMichaelTX Downvoting *is itself* constructive accurate feedback on the quality of a post.  No other feedback is often needed   It, alone, is *enormously* useful to the site, and is a key feature that is unfortunately extremely underutilized

Comment: Since you brought up the USA, do you send a letter to every candidate you didn't vote for, explaining why you voted against them? I sure don't, and it's my right to stay silent when I vote.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan:  You said:  " do you send a letter to every candidate you didn't vote for, explaining why you voted against them?" --- I can tell that you don't understand the political voting process.  We for FOR a candidate.  There is no provision to vote "against" a candidate.

Comment: @Servy:  You said:  "Downvoting is itself constructive accurate feedback on the quality of a post". --- It is neither constructive nor accurate unless the person also posts a comment as to why the downvote.  Otherwise, it is just random noise, hit or miss.  I'm sure you will disagree, so we will just have to agree to disagree.  :-)

Comment: @JMichaelTX If you vote for a candidate and not another, you are voting against a candidate. In any case, you apparently don't understand the political voting process, because, at least in my state, you don't have to tell anyone who you voted for or against, let alone why you voted the way you did.

Comment: @JMichaelTX So anyone that doesn't post a comment explaining why they voted cannot have had a reason for voting, and they must have voted randomly?  Sorry, but no.  Just because you don't know what the reason is, doesn't mean that there wasn't one, or that it was an unconstructive behavior.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan:  You said:  " If you vote for a candidate and not another, you are voting against a candidate." --- Actually, that's incorrect.  There could be 5 candidates available for the position.  I might like 3 of them, be ambivalent about one, and really dislike the other.  But with my vote FOR only one, it does not in any way reveal which one I really dislike.