# Why does the downvote privilege page contradict the tooltip?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvote-reason

It was brought to my attention earlier today due to an answer being posted (in which the question was a typographical error) that the [downvote privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) almost contradicted the tooltip shown for the downvote answer arrow. I was then linked [a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318655/5647260) regarding this topic, which I've read, but this matter is different. I've also read through [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2451/332767), but again the criteria isn't specific.

I've always understood the downvote (for answers) just as the tooltip suggests: *this answer is not helpful*. In other words, I've interpreted it as *"This answer won't help or provide any future readers any useful information"*, but the downvote privilege page mentions:

> **When should I vote down?**
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

Ok, I understand the criteria for questions (egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended). But the answer part is where it loses me. With my interpretation, *anything that will not help future users is worthy of a downvote*. To me, that includes:

- Blatantly wrong answers
- Spam or abusive answers
- Answers that will not help a broad audience
- Answers to primarily opinion based questions
- Link only answers

By 'Answers that will not help a broad audience', I mean something like a typographical error. The answer may be useful to the OP him or herself but not to a lot future readers (or the 'broader audience'). (The way I see the site's goal, we're not here to help any specific questioner, but to leave general answer to help many future readers).

Now, you can see a problem. My criteria for downvoting is more broad than the one in the privilege page site, encompassing more answers, but this still (**in my honest opinion**) is under the umbrella of 'this answer is not useful. This means that the page contradicts what the tooltip says. I suggest we change the privilege page to mention downvoting when the answer is not useful, not just because it's dangerously or blatantly wrong.

Comment: Very very related: [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions)

Comment: I don't think downvoting an answer to a typo question is good. While that might be okay if the answer was terrible/etc, just because it was pointing out the typo is not a valid reason to downvote.

Comment: @hichris123 thanks for the link; so then answers to bad questions like a typo are not downvote worthy even if the downvote tooltip says to downvote if the content isn't helpful? I can agree that downvoting answers to bad answers can be considered bad, but would that mean we have to change to tooltip description?

Comment: @hichris123 the downvotes serve as a disincentive for doing it again. The reasoning behind that is, if people answer typo questions, the message is sent that that's OK. Then we slide down the slope of eventually letting typo questions be on-topic on the site. We don't' want that to happen, so we discourage answering typo questions. How do we discourage it? Downvoting answers. Of course, not everyone agrees with this, but that's the beauty of your vote being your vote; you use it as you see fit.

Comment: I don't agree with your definition of downvotes on answers, and think they should mean that the answer is incorrect or dangerous. But regardless of which way this goes, the difference between the tooltip and the help center needs to be corrected.

Comment: @TylerH You downvote and delete the question. It's not the answer's fault that the question was off-topic. Again, if it's a terrible answer, feel free to downvote, but trying to "discourage" answers on typo-questions by downvoting is either sure to backfire or do absolutely nothing. Take care of the problem, not the symptom.

Comment: @hichris123 _delete the question_ These (undownvoted) answers make it harder to do that. Users that answer bad questions don't get any other feedback and therefore continue answering those posts. Downvotes can serve as that feedback. So can comments. In the case of a high reputation user that's going against the help center recommendations, you can't do anything. In the case of a low reputation user, the downvote will have a better chance of convincing them.

Comment: @hichris123 No, it's not the answerer's fault that the question is off-topic, but it is the answerer's fault for answering it. People answering bad questions is arguably a larger problem than people asking bad questions. If nobody answered bad questions, there'd be a helluva lot fewer bad questions asked. Failure to address this when users are new and impressionable leads to users being set in their way and/or developing a disregard for those who try to correct the behavior later on.

Comment: How does not downvoting an answer make it "harder" to delete a question, @SotiriosDelimanolis? As long as we're not talking a 20+ scored answer + question combo, the number of delete votes will be 3. And if we're talking on the roomba side... [downvoting just for the roomba is strictly forbidden.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307009/clean-up-by-downvoting-a-ridiculous-user-experience/307010#307010)

Comment: Then *comment*, @TylerH. Say "Hey, typo questions are seen as off-topic". Avoid unconstructive language like saying that it's worthless to answer those questions, etc (as those discussions spiral downwards quickly), but you don't downvote a post to "teach" the user a lesson. That won't teach them a single thing.

Comment: @hichris123 Comments can be ignored with impunity. A downvote sends a designed penalty to the answerer for posting bad content. I agree a comment is often helpful/useful, but a downvote helps drive it home.

Comment: This is just going to be one of those things that we have to agree to disagree on @TylerH...

Comment: @hichris123 I disagree that we have to agree

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [Contradictory guidelines for downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280651)

Comment: @hichris123: Your linked post disagrees with your conclusion that roomba-feeding votes are forbidden, strictly or otherwise: "Policing voting isn't really a solution here; it's hard, ethically-grey, and doesn't scale." Shog doesn't really *approve* of them (*especially* in tag cleanup), but *forbidding* them? Not even a little.

Comment: @NathanTuggy "Yeah... This is unacceptable." "But blindly downvoting answers to avoid... retagging? That's just wrong." "**This is why we can't have nice things**" If you don't call that forbidding, or at the very least *strongly* asserting that this shouldn't occur...

Comment: @hichris123: Like I said, Shog clearly doesn't like this sort of tag-cleanup roomba-feeding. But he *specifically* does not attempt to *forbid* it. Don't misrepresent him.

Comment: Obviously, he can't directly forbid it, @NathanTuggy, because he can't be watching over every SO user. And "doesn't like" is a weak statement for his wording. But, I guarantee that if this were to be occurring, action would be taken.

Comment: @hichris123: From one of Shog's comments there: "I explicitly avoided calling anyone out, @ Mogsdad. The behavior is the problem, not the people - that the system unintentionally encourages this behavior is the problem I propose to address." So no, I strongly doubt that even the *spotty, inconsistent policing* you suggest is in scope at all. That simply is not something he considers worth doing. The post is about systemic code changes, not promulgating community behavior changes.

Comment: This is far astray @NathanTuggy - if you want to discuss this, I'm in [chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).